# npm registry error shows different path than what is in npm get registry

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Currently I am getting an error when running an NPM command at work.

*Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established*

I updated my registry to http://registry.npmjs.org. It used to be https://registry.npmjs.org

When I try again it still uses the https url. I even did a cache clean --force.

Where else should I update this setting?

Comment: On HTTP that registry server responds with a `302` and then it redirects to HTTPS.